# Nextjs app, viewport acting weird on mobile devices

Tags: next.js, responsive-design, viewport, vercel

i have a problem with my nextjs app,on mobile devices content of the website is weirdly shrinked, everything works on computer.  this is a photo from device toolbar in chrome:

[image: image from chrome console]

and this is how it works on smartphone:

[image: image from smartphone]

i thought it is problem with viewport or smh this is my code from layout.tsx

```
 <html lang="en">
  <Head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  </Head>
  <body className={inter.className}>
    <div className="container ">
      <Nav />
      {children}
      <Footer />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

so i cant find a solution

Comment: Kinda looks like it's zoomed in on the Smartphone screenshot. Have tried checking what it looks like on other mobiles devices and brower ?

Comment: actually no, but website that i have created in react works normal and it is the same for other projects in  html/css/js. thats my link for this website:https://tm-dev.vercel.app/

Comment: Check the dev console on the link you provided, there is a react error there. Maybe we should start from there by solving that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78082764/12100921 hope this helps